# selection from a list python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to accept user inputs from a list of strings as arguments, such as

`x = get_user_input(['yes', 'no', 'maybe'])`

If the user doesn't enter an input from the list. Finally, the program should return the part of the list that the user selects.

Comment: You need to read the user input and check if it is one of the valid inputs

Comment: just start off with a best case scenario - user inputs something, and it is one of the required inputs - then modify the program to handle the error conditions.

Comment: What up OP? Check my ans.. pls mark it right if it works for you! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_user_input(allowed_choices):
    while True:
        s = raw_input("Enter your choice " + "/".join(allowed_choices) + ": ")
        if s in allowed_choices:
            return s

x = get_user_input(['yes', 'no', 'maybe'])
```

If you want case insensitive comparison, use `s.lower() in allowed_choices`.